# How can I hide the 'Desktop' icon in Windows 10 file explorer?

Tags: windows-10

I have been able to hide all the other 'This PC' folders (Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos). Changing the actual directory path was easy. Hiding them from view in File Explorer was also not too hard. I followed this tutorial: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-the-folders-from-this-pc-windows-10 and was able to hide them from view.

However, this has not worked for the Desktop directory. The actual path of the Desktop directory is not %USERPROFILE%, but some sort of link to it still appears in that directory when I'm using File Explorer.

Any tips?

Comment: "some sort of link" can you provide more details what you mean this?

Comment: Have you tried the tweaker mentioned in your link?....http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10

Comment: "some sort of link to it still appears in that directory" Screenshot would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions.

1. Hit Win+R to enter the Registry Editor.
2. Then paste: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}\PropertyBag** into the navigation bar.
3. You will arrive at a folder with two files. Right-click the blank area of the folder. Hover over "New" and hit "String Value".
4. Name the string "ThisPCPolicy"
5. Set it to a value of "Hide"
6. Exit out of Registry Editor and make sure File Explorer is not open.
7. Open File Explorer and it should be gone. If it's not, try closing and opening File Explorer one more time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you follow the link, you will see that those are precisely the instructions given there, i.e precisely the the ones I followed. It didn't work.

Comment: These are not the same once you get to step #3. I expanded on what they did... their steps did not work for me either, but this did. The main problem is there is no "ThisPCPolicy" at the Desktop folder, so you need to make one.

Comment: Let me know if the problem persists...

Comment: At the bottom of the page, they tell you to do that... they explicitly mention how Desktop doesn't have a "ThisPCPolicy" string. I assure you, I did that.

Comment: Perhaps I missed it. Hmm. Can you explain your issue a little more fully? How does %USERPROFILE%  play a part? If you follow this link: https://www.howtogeek.com/222057/how-to-remove-the-folders-from-%E2%80%9Cthis-pc%E2%80%9D-on-windows-10/, they have a software download that does it for you. It worked on my pc...